# error message when running "Quadrotor indoor SLAM demo"

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

When I tried to run the quadrotor demo [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_quadrotor/Tutorials/Quadrotor%20indoor%20SLAM%20demo) , I got the following error message:

```
[ERROR] [1332786035.950907356, 0.255000000]: Trajectory Server: Transform from /map to /base_link failed: Frame id /map does not exist! Frames (6): Frame /front_cam_link exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /base_link exists with parent NO_PARENT.
Frame /front_cam_optical_frame exists with parent /front_cam_link.
Frame /laser0_frame exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /sonar_link exists with parent /base_link.
 

[ERROR] [1332786036.383930902, 0.503000000]: Trajectory Server: Transform from /map to /base_link failed: Frame id /map does not exist! Frames (9): Frame /front_cam_link exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /base_link exists with parent /base_stabilized.
Frame /front_cam_optical_frame exists with parent /front_cam_link.
Frame /laser0_frame exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /sonar_link exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /base_footprint exists with parent /nav.
Frame /nav exists with parent NO_PARENT.
Frame /base_stabilized exists with parent /base_footprint.
 

[ INFO] [1332786036.541020052, 0.555000000]: lookupTransform base_footprint to /laser0_frame timed out. Could not transform laser scan into base_frame.
[rviz-9] process has died [pid 3011, exit code -11]. log files: /home/user/.ros/log/5e1b3464-7770-11e1-8b32-0023aea58509/rviz-9*.log


[ERROR] [1332786036.869724780, 0.750000000]: Trajectory Server: Transform from /map to /base_link failed: Frame id /map does not exist! Frames (9): Frame /front_cam_link exists with parent /base_link.
    Frame /base_link exists with parent /base_stabilized.
    Frame /front_cam_optical_frame exists with parent /front_cam_link.
    Frame /laser0_frame exists with parent /base_link.
    Frame /sonar_link exists with parent /base_link.
    Frame /base_footprint exists with parent /nav.
    Frame /nav exists with parent NO_PARENT.
    Frame /base_stabilized exists with parent /base_footprint.
     
    
    [ERROR] [1332786037.258785570, 1.004000000]: Trajectory Server: Transform from /map to /base_link failed: Frame id /map does not exist! Frames (9): Frame /front_cam_link exists with parent /base_link.
    Frame /base_link exists with parent /base_stabilized.
    Frame /front_cam_optical_frame exists with parent /front_cam_link.
    Frame /laser0_frame exists with parent /base_link.
    Frame /sonar_link exists with parent /base_link.
    Frame /base_footprint exists with parent /nav.
    Frame /nav exists with parent NO_PARENT.
    Frame /base_stabilized exists with parent /base_footprint.
     
    
    [ERROR] [1332786037.356971730, 1.055000000]: Transform failed during publishing of map_odom transform: Unable to lookup transform, cache is empty, when looking up transform from frame [/base_footprint] to frame [/nav]
```

Could anybody let me know how to resolve the error message ?

Thanks~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30497/error-message-when-running-%22quadrotor-indoor-slam-demo%22/) by [maruchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1429/maruchi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 157 on 2012-03-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most of these errors should be startup artifacts, when not all nodes are running yet. The main problem is that rviz seems to crash when trying to load the .vcg config file specified in the launch file. This seems to happen occasionally for no particular reason in electric. You can restart rviz afterwards and try to manually load the [indoor SLAM](http://code.google.com/p/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/source/browse/trunk/hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_demo/rviz_cfg/indoor_slam.vcg) .vcg config file. You can also just start up rviz and add displays that you´re interested in yourself.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [maruchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1429/maruchi/) on 2012-03-29**:
Hi Stefan, Even I do "roslaunch hector_quadrotor_demo  indoor_slam_gazebo.launch" with commenting rviz, the above error message comes out. Any suggestion ?

**Comment by [maruchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1429/maruchi/) on 2012-03-30**:
Stefan, Even though I get all the above message, I can see gazebo simulation with rviz, camera view. Is the above message just warning message due to others, for example, no maps or something ?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2012-04-03**:
These errors are just startup artifacts, as the whole tf tree is not yet available and nodes are started in more or less random order. As long as everything settles and works after 1-2 seconds just ignore them :)